# table td or (div) opacity change the rest of td or (div) when hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

When I hover a `td` element, how do I change the opacity for all `td` elements except the one being hovered?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/n9MmT/)

[image]

html:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>  
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: When hovering a table cell, he wants to change the opacity of all cells except the one being hovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I think, It will work on IE.

```
table:hover td img {
  opacity: .5;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
table td img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9MmT/3/)

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Create a rule for hovering over the table that alters the opacity of all of the images contained.  You can then create a rule for the *img* being hovered that sets the opacity to 1.  It's important to set the opacity of individual images rather than the whole table as a child cannot be more opaque than its parent.

```
table:hover td img {
    opacity: .5;
}
table td img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9MmT/1/

Comment: hi thank you for your clever answer is this posible to work also in IE8